# npm errors when the ionic/cordova plugin uses --variable

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

I have been going through a nightmare so I'd be grateful for any pointer you might have for the below issue.

I have an ionic project that worked perfectly fine and as I was preparing for the final build to push the apk to production, I probably updated something (cordova, npm or ionic) and now cannot install a package if there is a --variable. For instance, the below command

`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-play-games-services --variable APP_ID="XXXXXXX"`

throws the following error:

```
Adding cordova-plugin-play-games-services to package.json
npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME
npm ERR! Invalid tag name "APP_ID=XXXXXXXX": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/myuser/.npm/_logs/2019-11-22T15_05_18_908Z-debug.log
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-play-games-services APP_ID=XXXXXXXX exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

The following command on the other hand

`ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-admob-free --variable ADMOB_APP_ID="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"`

gives

```
Adding cordova-plugin-admob-free to package.json
npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 'MyApp' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 name can no longer contain capital letters
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'MyApp@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 Your package name is not valid, because 
npm ERR! 404  1. name can no longer contain capital letters
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/myuser/.npm/_logs/2019-11-22T15_10_22_657Z-debug.log
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
```

I can install packages just fine if there is no use of --variable. I have the following environment:

```
npm -v: 6.12.1
cordova -v: 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
ionic -v: 5.4.7
```

I initially thought my npm registry was the problem. I reinstalled it and reinstalled ionic and cordova, which led to no change. I, in fact, created even a brand new linux partition and installed everything from scratch and still get the above problems!

I'd be grateful if you could help me out of this nightmare!

Huge thanks in advance,

Doug

Comment: Maybe it's an issue with ionic version 5 ! try to downgrade your ionic to version @4and try to reinstall the package

Comment: Ahmed, Thank you very much for your help! Yes, that was the issue. Again, very grateful for your time and help on this. Have a great day!